# Removing phantom display screens in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I usually work with 2 additional display monitors with my Windows 10 laptop. I see 4 additional displays phantom screens in the display settings. The detect or disconnect this display doesn't work as well.

Even if I remove all the displays, I still 4 additional display. How should I remove those. I don't have or use the New Desktop in the Windows 10 when do `WIN + TAB`

[image]

[image]

Comment: We are always glad to help, but there are already several questions within the Super User realm regarding this specific problem.  Please see the "Possible duplicate" reference.

Answer (score 0):

Download the [Intel driver updater tool](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/detect.html)

Install any display drivers that are available. The phantom monitors will disappear after the correct drivers are installed.

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User!  We value the contributions from our community members, but please remember to perform a search pertaining to any problem that seems relatively common before posting an answer.  This particular scenario has been the source of many Super User questions already.